# $xf'(x) = αf(x)$. How to prove that $f(x) = cx^\alpha$?

Tags: derivatives, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Let $f$ be a differentiable function such that $xf'(x) = \alpha f(x)$ for all $x > 0$.

How do I show that $f(x) = cx^\alpha$ for some constant $c$?

I have $f'(x) = \alpha f(x)/x$ , and I can see that $\alpha$ is the original power and $x$ is the denominator to make the power $(\alpha-1)$, as usual in differentiation, but I don't know how to show this mathematically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Hint:* Show that $g(x) := f(x)x^{-\alpha}$ is constant.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to get it from this! Also thanks for fixing my title and formatting!

Comment: This is called the method of the "integrating factor".

Answer (score 2):

By solving the differential equation, e.g. $y = f(x)$ and separation of variables. For $x > 0$ we have
$$
x \frac{dy}{dx} = \alpha y \Rightarrow \\
\int \frac{dy}{y} = \alpha \int \frac{dx}{x} \Rightarrow \\
\ln(y) = \alpha \ln(x) + C \Rightarrow \\
y = e^{C} x^{\alpha}
$$
Alternative: As you have given a candidate solution 
$$
f(x) = c x^\alpha
$$
you could check if it fulfills the differential equation:
$$
x f'(x) = x (\alpha c x^{\alpha - 1}) = \alpha(c x^\alpha) = \alpha f(x)
$$
which seems the case.

Answer (score 1):

Define $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x^a}$ for all $x \neq 0$. Now
\begin{align}
g'(x) = \frac{f'(x) x^a - f(x) a x^{a-1}}{x^{2a}} = \frac{f(x) a x^{a-1} - f(x) a x^{a-1}}{x^{2a}} = 0\,.
\end{align}
Thus $g$ is constant.